# how to use angular pipe as a shared component or shared module

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6

I am using below function as a pipe, for get unique values to the drop down. i need to use this in multiple components. how i create reusable component to use this function.

```
 @Pipe({
  name: 'unique',
  pure: false
})

export class UniquePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any): any {
      if (value !== undefined && value !== null) {
          return _.uniqBy(value, 'orgName');
      }
      return value;
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'shared' Do you mean using it on multiple component htmls?

Comment: yes i need to use this in multiple component

Comment: You don't need to do anything extra. Just import it into the respective modules, and you can use it on your components.

Comment: This is not what pipes are designed for. They should be used for formatting data when printing to view, not for arbitrary data manipulation. App logic belongs to the component code, not to the template.

Answer (score 7):

> Simply create a module named as `SharedModule` and then export the
>   pipe from it. That way it will be available as the public API for any
>   of the modules that import `SharedModule`.

Example:

```js
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { UniquePipe} from './pipes/unique.pipe';




@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    UniquePipe,
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    HttpClientModule,
  ],
  exports: [
    UniquePipe,
  ]
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

You can read more about this at:

1. https://angular.io/guide/sharing-ngmodules#sharing-modules
2. Style Guide: https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#shared-feature-module

Answer (score 3):

In your `shared.module.ts` file  you just need to add it in `declarations` and `exports` and then you can import this module in any other module where you want to use this pipe.

in `pipe.components.ts`

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({
  name: 'mypipe',
})
export class MyPipe implements PipeTransform {
  // convert dictionary to list so that it can be iterated in html
  transform(objects: any = []) {
    return Object.values(objects);
  }
}
```

then in your `shared.module.ts` :

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ValueArrayPipe } from '../pipe/pipe.component';


@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule
    ],
    declarations: [ValueArrayPipe ],
exports: [ValueArrayPipe ],
})
export class SharedPipesModule { }
```